# PDO insert not working, but no error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (time, sender_id, recipient_id, read, subject, content, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$q->execute(array($date->format('U'), $ID, $_POST['to'], "0", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['content'], 1));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

This code does not actually insert anything in the database. No error, and it even echo's 1, meaning it did work. But nothing shows up in my database.

If i add: `or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true))`
to the end of the execute line, it outputs: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` 
which I'm not really sure what that means.

Any idea? I know how pdo works and really can not figure this out.

Comment: Try `$q->errorInfo()` and `$q->rowCount()`.

Comment: `read` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) that needs to be escaped with backticks `$q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (time, sender_id, recipient_id, \`read\`, subject, content, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");`

Comment: Sean, that was it! thanks!